# iOS Face Recognition

Tags: ios, image, photo, face-recognition

I want to develop an application that recognizes a person in an image like the iPhone's Photos application.

What is the Apple's framework that should be used to achieve such a feature ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vision

Apply high-performance image analysis and computer vision techniques to identify faces, detect features, and classify scenes in images and video.

see in Apple Docs here [vision](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision)